# Recoloring Lines in rulercompass

Tags: color, tikz-styles, rules

I have the following tikz diagram using the rulercompass library.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[stop jumping ,constrain]
\path  (1, 0)  node [ruler compass/point=red, label={1}];
\path  (-1, 0) node[ruler compass/point=red, label={-1}];
\ruler{a}{b}
\compass{a}{b}
\compass{b}{a}
\point{cab}{cba}{1}
\point{cab}{cba}{2}
\path (c) node [ruler compass/point=red, label={$\sqrt{3}i$}];
\path (d) node [ruler compass/point=red, label={$-\sqrt{3}i$}];
\ruler{c}{d}
\point{rab}{rcd}{1}
\path (g) node [ruler compass/point=red, label={0}];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The lines drawn by \ruler and \compass are blue by default. How do I change their color? Neither of:

```
\ruler[gray]{a}{b}
\ruler[color=gray]{a}{b}
```

worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a key `ruler compass/construction in use` that can be used to set the style for individual `\ruler` and `\compass` commands.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{rulercompass}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[stop jumping ,constrain]
\path  (1, 0)  node [ruler compass/point=red, label={1}];
\path  (-1, 0) node[ruler compass/point=red, label={-1}];
\ruler[ruler compass/construction in use/.style={draw=red}]{a}{b}
\compass{a}{b}
\compass[ruler compass/construction in use/.style={draw=gray}]{b}{a}
\point{cab}{cba}{1}
\point{cab}{cba}{2}
\path (c) node [ruler compass/point=red, label={$\sqrt{3}i$}];
\path (d) node [ruler compass/point=red, label={$-\sqrt{3}i$}];
\ruler{c}{d}
\point{rab}{rcd}{1}
\path (g) node [ruler compass/point=red, label={0}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

I found this key by looking in the source of `rulercompass` for the value `blue`, which occurs a single time when the default value of the key is set.

If you want to set the default value yourself you can use

```
\tikzset{ruler compass/construction in use/.style={
    draw=gray
  }
}
```

before `\begin{tikzpicture}`.